# Compute $2i\Re(z)\Im(z) = \bar{z} + 3 + i$

Tags: complex-numbers

Compute: $2i\Re(z)\Im(z) = \bar{z} + 3 + i$

How do you solve this? What do you change $\Re(z), \Im(z)$ to? I tried it like this, but I'm unsure if I've done it right;

$2i·a·bi = a-bi+3+i$

$i(b-1) - 2ab-a-3=0,$ therefore: $b=1$ and $a=-1$, the solution: $z = 1+i$

Is this the correct process?

Comment: Something like that should work, but **note** that the imaginary part of $a+bi$ is $b$, not $bi$.

Comment: As a start, the left side is a real times $i$. Thus so is the right side, and therefore the real part of $\bar{z}$, and hence of $z$, is $-3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2*i*a*b=a-bi+3+i$$
$$2iab=a+3+i(1-b)$$

How would you find a and b now?

Comment: Oh. I see somebody did that after me. I hope you get it now. :)

Answer (score 0):

$2iab = 3+a + (1-b)i \Rightarrow a = -3$ and $b = -\frac{1}{5}$.